# Iterative hash/checksum algorithm

Tags: c++, hash, parallel-processing, checksum

I need to generate a single checksum of a very large file for data validation (xxhash, sha256 or similar) on multiple compute nodes.

Currently multiple nodes (concurrently) contributes to generate this large file: they do some computation, once done they lock the file and then write their result to the same file (file is on a parallel file-system). Generating the checksum as a post-process is not ideal since I would like to calculate the checksum while the new content is in memory of the processing node.

Preferably I would like that when a node is ready to dump its data to the file, it would read the latest checksum from a sidecar file, update the checksum with the new content (continuing from the previous checksum) and then save the new checksum to the sidecar file.

Is there any hash/checksum algorithms that can do this (essentially restore its state from a previous hash).

(In the case of xxh64 I could possibly dump/restore the state struct to the sidecar file but it's essentially internal so that does not seem to be an ideal approach)

Comment: It would seem that you also need the hash result to be the same regardless of the order the parts are hashed in. That requirement seems to be implied by your scenario (concurrent processing, update a single hash value). This substantially weakens the hash and unsurprisingly there are no well-regarded hashes that I'm aware of that do this. You can always make up your own hash with this property.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how nodes write data in the same file ? Is the position written data associated to the node, or data are appended to the end without any ordering guarantee or is the order of the appending guaranteed by synchronizations between the nodes ? Is the written block size known ahead of time ? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The order is synchronized since each node locks the file when it's about to write (fcntl write lock) and appends at the end. Thus the order the different nodes write to the output is not known, but it does not matter for the data itself. The resulting hash would be different depending on the order the nodes writes, but that's ok as long as I would get the same result if I later checksum the entire file at once.

Comment: Also I realize I probably need to: 
1) lock the output file. 
2) load previous checksum, calculate new checksum with new data + old checksum. 
3) append the new data to the output file. 
4) write the new checksum to the sidecar file. 
5) unlock the output file.

Comment: I guess this question is similar in how would you go about having a checksum of a live stream of video (the entire stream so far), even if the process recording the live stream might have been restarted from time to time (and you don't want to run the checksum process from the start of the stream every time you restart the process).

Answer (score 1):

CRCs can be stitched together from the CRCs of individual blocks but cryptographic hashes cannot.

However, even cryptographic hashes usually allow incremental operation. If your file is only ever appended to (no overwriting of older, already-hashed data) then you can simply keep the hasher **state data** in the 'sidecar' file. However, this prolongs locking time and contention since the hash for the block to be appended can only be computed after locking and loading the hash state, and the lock can only be released after the hash state has been written back.

IOW, the append-and-update-hash operation needs to be effectively serialised. It is not sufficient to keep the lock only until a sufficient byte range in the file has been reserved, to be written at leisure later without locks, unless the hash update operation (load-hash-save) is serialised by some other means.

An alternative could be the use of hash trees a.k.a. [Merkle trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) (more a twig than a tree in this case). You record the offsets, lengths and hashes of the individual blocks in your sidecar file and your checksum is the hash over this file, not a hash over the big file.

This allows the hash of an append block to be calculated beforehand. The locking on the sidecar file *replaces* the locking on the target file; the target file only needs to be extended/enlarged under the lock but the actual writing can be done later without locks.